# File not found error when trying to load image

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code to show the image of a product when the Product Name is clicked and in the case when the Product has no image I specified a "Not available" image tht will be displayed instead but I keep getting "File not found" instead of the Not available image.

````
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
Dim strFile As String
Dim ProductName As String
Dim iPath As String
Dim iPathNA As String

ProductName = Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 1)
iPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Item Images\" & ProductName & ".JPG"
iPathNA = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Item Images\NA.jpg"

strFile = iPath

If strFile = "" Then
    Image2.Picture = LoadPicture(iPathNA)
Else
    Image2.Picture = LoadPicture(strFile)
End If
End Sub ```
````

Comment: Check if the file exists with `len(dir(strFile)) <> 0`

Comment: What's the value of _iPath_ and _strFile_? strFile will never be an empty string.

Comment: If "Not available image" is in the `NA` picture, its full name is wrong... You should check if in code, or visually.

Comment: Thank you very much @milo5m its wotking now

Answer (score 3):

This code solved the problem with the help of @milo5m

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    Dim strFile As String
    
    Me.cmb_Product.Value = Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 0)
    iPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Item Images\" & Me.cmb_Product.Value & ".JPG"
    iPathNA = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Item Images\NA.jpg"
    
    strFile = iPath
    
    If Len(Dir(strFile)) <> 0 Then
        ItemImage.Picture = LoadPicture(strFile)
    Else
        ItemImage.Picture = LoadPicture(iPathNA)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This line `FileExists = Dir(strFile)` is not needed and does nothing useful unless you alternatively use `If Len(FileExists) <> 0 Then` and declare `Dim FileExists As String`. I recommend to use `Option Explicit` to avoid variables that are not declared properly.